# Python sort list of dictionary by last name

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort the dep_list, which is a list of dictionaries containing employee information (name, department, position, salary). Right now I believe I have it sorting by first name, however I want to sort by last name. If at all possible without breaking the 'name' up into 2 different strings.

```
#Function for adding employee information
def add_emp():
    #Ask the user to add an employee
    print("Enter the employee's information:\n")
    #Input first and last name
    name = str(input("What is the employee's name? ")).title()
    #Input employee position
    position = str(input("What is their position? ")).title()
    #Input employee department
    em_department = str(input("What is their department? ")).title()
    #Make sure the salary is numeric
    try:
        #Input employee salary
        salary = round(float(input("What is their salary? ")), 2)
        #Add information to a dictionary called employees
        employees[name] = {"name": name, "position": position,     "em_department": em_department, "salary": salary}
    except:
        print("Salaries must be numeric, silly!")

#Function for adding employees to dictionary by department
def dep_emp():
    #Go through all department names stored in the tuple
    for x in dep_tup:
        #Initialize department list each time to ensure correct sorting
        dep_list = []
        #Go through all employee dictionaries; when matched, add to the list associated with the corresponding key in the dep_dict dictionary
        for names in employees:
            if x == employees[names]["em_department"]:
                dep_list.append(employees[names])
                dep_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
                dep_dict[x] = dep_list
                continue
```

Note: The list of dictionaries looks like this:
{

department1: [{'name': name, 'em_department': department, 'position': position, 'salary': salary}, ...],

department2: [...]

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dep_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'].split()[-1])
```

For each dictionary in `dep_list`, find the value associated with the `name` key, split it, and sort based on the last string in the split (should be the last name).